# Print some JSON

Tags: code-golf, open-ended-function, json

This challenge is straightforward, but hopefully, there are plenty of avenues you can approach it:

**You need to print/return a valid JSON *object* of at least 15 characters, not counting unessential whitespace.**  Your program should work without any input.

In the interest of clarity, a JSON object starts and ends with curly braces `{}`, and contains zero or more key:value pairs separated by commas.  The full JSON specification can be found at [json.org](http://www.json.org/), and the output of your code must pass [this validator](http://jsonlint.com/#).

Therefore, any of the following would **not** be valid:

```
4                               //Too short, not an object
"really, really long string"    //A string, not an object
["an","array","of","values"]    //An array is not a JSON object
{"this":4      }                //You can't count unessential whitespace
{"1":1,"2":3}                   //Too short
{"a really long string"}        //Not valid JSON, it needs a value
{'single-quoted':3}             //JSON requires double-quotes for strings
```

However, the following *would* be valid:

```
{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4}       //Long enough
{"whitespace      ":4}          //This whitespace isn't unessential
```

Non-programming languages are allowed on this challenge.  You may return a string from a function, or print it out.  This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so answer it with as little code as possible!

Comment: I like the variety of answers on this one

Comment: Hmmmm, your definition of JSON is limited. What about code that ouputs valid JSON but does not output curly braces?

Comment: @Konijn like I said, it must be a valid JSON *object*.  The object is defined by the curly braces.

Comment: Got it, with stress on object ;)

Comment: What exactly counts as a JSON object, because the JS code `_=>_={100:_}` would return a valid JSON object, just not in a string. Don't forget to put `f=` before the code and call like `f()`

Comment: @Masterzagh Unfortunately, a native JS object doesn't count.  "You may return a string from a function, or print it out"

Comment: @NathanMerrill Oh I'm blind, sorry

Answer (score 75):

### Python 2, 14 bytes

```python
print{`str`:1}
```

Outputs:

```
{"<type 'str'>": 1}
```

The backticks get the string representation in Python 2. Usually, this outputs inside creates single quotes, which Python recognizes as delimiting a string, but JSON doesn't. But Sp3000 observes that when stringifying a type, the type description already contains single quotes, which forces the outer quotes to be double quotes.

Comment: @Sp3000 That's beautiful in an awful way.

Comment: And I thought JS was the only language you can truly abuse type casting in...

Comment: same approach works for py3 with 20 bytes `print({repr(str):1})`

Comment: @dahrens for Py3: `print({"'"*9:9})` for 16 (`print{"'"*9:9}` is another 14 in Py2)

Comment: `\`id\`` is one shorter, and outputs more JSON

Comment: @pxeger `id` gives `{'<built-in function id>': 1}` which isn't valid json

Answer (score 41):

## jq, 6 characters

(3 characters code + 3 characters command-line option.)

```
env
```

CW because I am sure this is not the kind of answer you intended to allow.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n 'env'
{
  "GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE": "1",
  "TERM": "xterm",
  "SHELL": "/bin/bash",
  "GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES": "1",
  "XTERM_LOCALE": "en_US.UTF-8",
  "XTERM_VERSION": "XTerm(322)",
  "GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE": "1",
  "GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM": "auto",
  "_": "/usr/bin/jq"
}
```

(Output obviously shortened.)

Comment: This is definitely a valid submission (and no need to CW)

Comment: Also, http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/how-should-community-wikis-be-used

Comment: Certainly valid. But I see no way to make a relevant comparison with any other solution, in this question's context. That is why I feel it should stand aside.

Comment: This counts as offloading the solution to a built in, which is almost a forbidden loophole. Keyword: almost

Comment: @JanDvorak It is not always a loophole, because there are cases where it is interesting to see a built-in used. This is one of them.

Comment: I won't do it against your explicit wishes, but I agree that this should be unwikied. Also, [current consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/12012) is that interpreter flags have to count the difference between invocation with and without the flag, so `-n` and a space account for three extra bytes.

Comment: @Dennis, I still feel this is an unfair competitor. But after all, I also feel is unfair to count a space used due to shell syntax, that never reaches the interpreter. Whatever.

Answer (score 33):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Ɠɼ'ẸẠḌȷżÑ»
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcxpPJvCfhurjhuqDhuIzIt8W8w5HCuw&input=)

#### Output

```
{"Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch":0}
```

Comment: Is that one word, or multiple? o_o

Comment: [Not a rickroll.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHxO0UdpoxM)

Comment: It has 6 consonants in a row twice (`pwllgw` and `bwllll`).  What even is this?

Comment: How does this even work...

Comment: @Oliver it's a compression of the whole output string (everything between `“` and `»`). The long Welsh place name is in the dictionary Jelly has. See section 3.1.2 of [the tutorial](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Tutorial)

Comment: @StevenH. "W" is sometimes a vowel in Welsh (for example in [crwth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crwth))

Comment: @StevenH. As Robert says, `w` can be a vowel in Welsh. As for the `llll`, I believe it is supposed to be parsed as `l-ll-l`, `ll` being considered as a single letter.

Comment: Is there really no word with shorter compressed output?

Comment: @ETHproductions Sure, but I need at least 9 letters to comply with the limit. All words with 6+ letters are in the long dictionary, so it doesn't really matter which one you pick.

Comment: @Fatalize. [Welsh letters are interesting](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93027/4134).

Comment: @Dennis. [Also not a rickroll, but a song nonetheless](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BXKsQ2nbno).

Comment: Wait, Jelly has a built-in for *this*?

Comment: @TheBitByte [why do we even have that lever?](https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-09/24/14/enhanced/webdr08/anigif_original-grid-image-24542-1411583964-9.gif)

Comment: Definitely +1 for the craziest label name I have ever seen. I'd hate to have to work with one of your web services.

Answer (score 22):

## Notepad, 7 keystrokes

If you have a Windows computer with the Notepad program, type this:

<kbd>{</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

On my Windows 7 computer, at least, this gives you something like:

```
{"3:42 PM 10/25/2016":0}
```

Comment: A programming language?

Comment: @cat It's a program, not a programming language, but then again, I believe Vim is the same.

Comment: Well, Vim *is* a programming "language", both in that it fulfills PPCG rules (not Turing completeness) but also in Turing completeness (at least, I'm pretty sure)

Comment: You should ping [@DJMCMayhem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem) in chat to learn more, for they are a Vim wizard and I am merely a mortal onlooker.

Comment: @cat I see. I'm not sure if Notepad is Turing-complete. I doubt it, but perhaps; after all, /// has been proven so, and Notepad can pretty well recreate its single feature.

Comment: Vim is different from Notepad - you can save a script and run it within the editor. There is no such feature in Notepad. Thus, the features in Notepad (rudimentary search-and-replace, copying, and pasting) that allow it to be TC require navigating dialogs each time - which means more keystrokes.

Comment: @Mego Yes, I'm aware of that. It doesn't make it any less TC, but it does make it terrible for golfing any non-kolgomorov-complexity challenges...

Comment: @cat btw, the OP has explicitly allowed non-programming-language entries.

Comment: @ETHproductions This was never debated but I think that was added after my comment.

Comment: @cat Yeah, sorry, I meant it has been allowed since our discussion.

Comment: Based on memories of keyboard parsing from old DOS days, I suspect this should be counted as 8 bytes. There are two-byte encodings for F5 in many character sets designed for communicating keypresses to an application, and these are commonly seen on DOS (thus indirectly Windows), but I'm not aware of a character set that uses a one-byte encoding.

Comment: Is <kbd>"</kbd> 1 byte?

Answer (score 17):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 20 bytes

```java
v->"{\"\":"+1/.3+"}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoIwGIT3PsWfTqBSY9xEGd2cSFzEoYKQYmkb@peEEJ69VmS63N131/KBJ2318aIzukdog2cOhWS1UyUKrdgmJcS4lxQllJJbCzcuFEwEYE0tcgwyaFFBF7oox16o5vEE3jc2XlCA6/p3vgdu90cyqOECfkgyOhW0oCe6PezZcUtn6tNllY8W3x3TDpkJC5Qqqhk3Ro6RclLG8Q@byey/)

### Output

```java
{"":3.3333333333333335}
```

Comment: Java is the last language I would expect to overload `+` to `String.concat` >:^(

Comment: @cat Yes, it's actually the only overload that exists. The thing is it doesn't even overload `String.concat`! If you check the bytecode, this is what Java compiles into: `()->new StringBuilder("{\"\":").append(1/.3).append("}").toString()`. Also, don't worry, this is still the longest answer on this page, bar the Brainfuck one and the Java 7 one. So Java holds its rank ;)

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

Thanks to @Neil for this one. Call with no input.

```
_=>`{"${_}":0}`
```

Outputs `{"undefined":0}`

#### Old version, 16 bytes

Thanks to @kamoroso94 for -1 on this version

```
_=>`{"":${9e9}}`
```

Outputs `{"":9000000000}`

Comment: You could turn this into an arrow function to remove 4 bytes.

Comment: Can you have an empty key? (e.g. remove `a`)

Comment: `_=>\`{"a":${_}}\`` results in `{"a":undefined}`, which is exactly 15 characters. Noted that you don't use any input when calling this function

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub Coincidentally, your code is also 15 characters. I'm not sure that `undefined` is a valid value in JSON, but that's readily fixed by making it the property name and using a zero value: `_=>\`{"${_}":0}\``.

Comment: Remove the `a` to make the key the empty string, a valid key in JSON.  1 less byte.

Comment: Does it have to be a function at all? Can't it just be the \`{"":${9e9}}\`.

Comment: How does this print out anything? It's a function that isn't being called. You should at least add (...)() to it. And then you only have a return value, and not something printed out

Comment: @nl-x, oh yeah. I wasn't paying enough attention to the "print" part of the challenge. In a javascript console, it will implicitly return the result of any expression, so I was thinking that might be sufficient, but yeah... no so.

Comment: @nl-x The OP has edited to clarify that functions returning the string are allowed.

Comment: @RobertHickman ^

Comment: This is a lot similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97426/14732 (which was answered 1 hour before your last edit.) On a *regular* environment, without **any** library, both answers are identical. On a website that *happens* to have jQuery, both are different. I'm not accusing of anything, I'm just exposing this bit.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That's fair... not sure what I should do about it though. You can see the edit history to see that my original version was a bit longer, but I edited it to reflect Neil's suggestion

Comment: @jrich I know. I don't know what you should do either. I would upvote the other answer and show this on meta and ask for guidance.

Answer (score 14):

## PHP, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
{"":<?=M_E?>}
```

Prints a <s>nice</s> mathsy object <s>that one could almost pretend is useful</s>:

```
{"":2.718281828459}
```

Uses the fact that php prints anything outside the tags verbatim to save on some quotation marks, `M_E` was the shortest long enough constant I could find.

edit: saved one byte thanks to Lynn. Sadly it's no longer a 'nice' mathsy object.

Comment: `""` is a valid JSON key.

Answer (score 13):

### Brainfuck, 50 bytes

```
+[+<---[>]>+<<+]>>+.>>>--.<+++<[->.<]>>.<+.-.<<++.
```

Outputs `{"999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999":9}`. Assumes an interpreter that has 8-bit cells and is unbounded on the left. [Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1srPC0tLVs-XT4rPDwrXT4-Ky4-Pj4tLS48KysrPFstPi48XT4-LjwrLi0uPDwrKy4&input=)

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth - 5 bytes

Prints `{"'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'": 10}`.

```
XH`GT
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=XH%60GT&debug=0).

Comment: JSON only allows double quotes unfortunetly

Comment: @Downgoat ah, fixing for one byte.

Comment: @Downgoat fixed.

Answer (score 11):

## Jolf, 9 bytes

```
"{¦q:¦q}"
```

Outputs: `{"{¦q:¦q}":"{¦q:¦q}"}`. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=InvCpnE6wqZxfSI)

```
"{¦q:¦q}"
"{  :  }"  raw string
  ¦q       insert the source code here
     ¦q    and here
```

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
.d],`G0
```

Creates a dictionary containing a single key `"'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"` and value `0`:

```
.d         Dictionary from:
  ]         The single-element list containing:
   ,         The two-element list containing:
    `G        The representation of the alphabet (the key)
      0       and 0 (the value)
          Implicitly print the stringification of this.
```

Answer (score 9):

## ///, <s>15</s> 14 characters

```
/a/{":1234}/aa
```

(At least the output is <s>1</s> 2 characters longer than the code.)

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L2EveyI6MTIzNH0vYWE&input=)

Thanks to:

- [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) for reusing the object delimiters as part of key (-1 character)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ slashes.pl <<< '/a/{":1234}/aa'
{":1234}{":1234}
```

Just to make it more readable:

```
bash-4.3$ slashes.pl <<< '/a/{":1234}/aa' | jq ''
{
  ":1234}{": 1234
}
```

Comment: That's a clever way to save bytes :-)

Comment: You can save another one with `/a/{":1234}/aa` (outputs `{":1234}{":1234}`)

Comment: Amazing, @ETHproductions. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

### Batch, 16 bytes

Prints `{"Windows_NT":0}`.

```
@echo {"%OS%":0}
```

Comment: Could you please add the (example) output?

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

Unfortunately, 05AB1E doesn't have a dictionary object so we have to construct our own.

```
’{"èÖ":7}
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZeyLDqMOWIjo3fQ&input=)

**Output**

```
{"dictionaries":7}
```

Answer (score 7):

## R, 19 bytes

```
cat('{"',lh,'":1}')
```

Becomes a bit longer because the need to escape quotes `\"`. Furthermore, `lh` is one of the built-in datasets in `R` and is (to my knowledge) the object with the shortest name that contains the 9 characters needed to fill the length of the key. (edit: turns out `pi` does the trick as well with the standard option and I was beaten by @JDL who was clever enough to escape using single quotes rather than the extra backslashes)

The description of `lh` in the R-documentation is:

> A regular time series giving the luteinizing hormone in blood samples at 10 mins intervals from a human female, 48 samples.

which is a rather unexpected name of a key, but hey, it works and produces the output:

```
{" 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.2 2.1 1.5 2.3 2.3 2.5 2 1.9 1.7 2.2 1.8 3.2 3.2 2.7 2.2 2.2 1.9 1.9 1.8 2.7 3 2.3 2 2 2.9 2.9 2.7 2.7 2.3 2.6 2.4 1.8 1.7 1.5 1.4 2.1 3.3 3.5 3.5 3.1 2.6 2.1 3.4 3 2.9 ":1}
```

The answer can be compared to just padding the key with "random" letters to make the output at least 15 characters (24 bytes):

```
cat("{\"HeloWorld\":1}")
```

Comment: You can avoid the escaping backslashes by using single quotes in the R expression: `cat('{"',lh,'":1}')` as I did above (though I used `pi` instead of `lh`). In my search for two-letter variables I came across the function `el` which I never knew existed. Could be useful in future...

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 14 Bytes

```
'{"":'+1tb+'}'
```

Output

```
{"":1099511627776}
```

Using the constant defined for 1TB in bytes to reach the character limit and the value of a static integer to make for valid json. Thanks to TimmyD for reducing the characters by 5 by removing some redundancy.

---

#### Earlier Post 40 Bytes

```
"{$((1..9|%{'"{0}":{0}'-f$_})-join",")}"
```

Output

```
{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9}
```

Takes a integer array and creates a key-value pair for each. Join with commas and wrap with a set of curly braces.

Answer (score 6):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 9 bytes

```
i{"¹*":0}
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=aXsiwrkqIjowfQ&input=)

Very straightforward. Enters insert mode, enters the following text:

```
{"*********":0}
```

The reason this is so short is because `¹` repeats the following character 9 times.

Comment: I was expecting the 0 byte one :P

Comment: @maltysen I did post it. I deleted it because it used single quotes instead of double... :(

Answer (score 6):

### Retina, 11 bytes

```retina
 
{"9$*R":1}
```

#### Output

```
{"RRRRRRRRR":1}
```

**Note:** the leading newline is significant as nothing is replaced with the resultant output, I've used a non-breaking space to illustrate this!

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CnsiOSQqUiI6MX0&input=)

Answer (score 6):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
⎕JSON⎕DMX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9oCgzr@T/o76pXsH@fkDKxTcCJPwfLA4A)

In a clean workspace on my PC the result is

`{"Category":"","DM":[],"EM":"","EN":0,"ENX":0,"HelpURL":"","InternalLocation":["",0],"Message":"","OSError":[0,0,""],"Vendor":""}`

`⎕JSON` convert to JSON

`⎕DMX` the (universally available) **D**iagnostic **M**essage E**x**tended object

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-Q`, 1 byte

```
M
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=TQ==&input=LVE=)

The output is `{"P":3.141592653589793,"Q":1.618033988749895,"T":6.283185307179586}`.

#### How it works

`M` is a shorthand for JS's `Math` object, with one-char aliases to existing functions/constants and some extra functions/constants. The constants shown here are:

- `M.P = Math.PI`
- `M.Q = Golden Ratio = (Math.sqrt(5)+1)/2`
- `M.T = Math.PI * 2`

And the boring part: [the `-Q` flag applies `JSON.stringify` to the output value](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/blob/90d14016a5a4675c8c20243cb63ccbcea830c0b6/src/japt.js#L2122). Some of the properties are lost (e.g. `Math.E` and `Math.SQRT2`), but we still have the above three values and the result is well over 15 characters.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, 19 bytes

```
puts'{"1":'+9**9+?}
```

Output:

```
{"1":387420489}
```

Comment: @NathanMerrill Fixed

Comment: Can you show what it outputs

Comment: Can't you save a byte by removing the space after `puts`?

Comment: I think that `?1*9` is still long enough.

Comment: @curiousdannii Done

Comment: @Oliver I did that

Comment: @LeeW Fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

## brainfuck, 83 bytes

```
--[-->+++++<]>.+[---->+<]>+++.>-[>+<-----]>.........<<.[----->+<]>.>.>--[-->+++<]>.
```

Outputs `{"333333333":3}`

There is likely another shorter solution, but I have not yet found it.

Explanation:

```
--[-->+++++<]>. {
+[---->+<]>+++. "
>-[>+<-----]>.  3
........
<<.             "
[----->+<]>.    :
>.              3
>--[-->+++<]>.  }
```

[Try it online](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LS1bLS0-KysrKys8XT4uIHsKK1stLS0tPis8XT4rKysuICIKPi1bPis8LS0tLS1dPi4gIDMKLi4uLi4uLi4KPDwuICAgICAgICAgICAgICIKWy0tLS0tPis8XT4uICAgIDoKPi4gICAgICAgICAgICAgIDMKPi0tWy0tPisrKzxdPi4gIH0$)

Answer (score 5):

## R, 19 bytes

This works in British English locale; it may require +2 bytes in others. (Edit: it probably doesn't --- see comments.)

```
cat('{"',pi,'":1}')
```

I was hoping for something clever (perhaps plucking a line of code out of a pre-existing function like `q`) but couldn't find anything. The result:

```
{" 3.141593 ":1}
```

Note that you don't have to escape double quotes in R if you use single quotes to quote the string (and vice-versa). This behaviour is locale-dependent though. I would expect it to work in a US English locale as well though.

This also requires that your default `digits` option is at least six (which is the factory-fresh default) and that `scipen` is at least `-digits` (the factory-fresh default is zero).

Comment: Sorry, what? R's grammar changes with locale?

Comment: Yes, which characters need escaping depends on `options(quote)` which can be specified by the user, but the default is, as far as I know, locale-dependent.

Comment: @cat I think that’s a misunderstanding. The existence of `options('quote')` [isn’t](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) [documented](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html), changing it has no discernible effect, and though I’ve come across a great deal of shenanigans in R I doubt that runtime options would change the way it’s parsed. It may change the output of course — but not in the code in this answer.

Comment: @Konrad, you might be right. I think I was thinking of "useFancyQuotes" which only affects `quote`, `squote` etc.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 7, 36 bytes

```
String c(){return"{\"a\":"+1e6+"}";}
```

## Java 8, 21 bytes

```
()->"{\"a\":"+1e6+"}"
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/p0m9uT)

```
class M{
  static String c(){
    return "{\"a\":" + 1e6 + "}";
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c());
  }
}
```

**Output (length 15):**

```
{"a":1000000.0}
```

Comment: Second solution  gives an error

Comment: @Numberknot Fixed and added to the test code

Comment: "length varies between 15 and 16 depending on the hash". Hashes can technically have a length as small as `1` ([see `System.identityHashCode(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-)).

Comment: Also, you can golf 1 byte by using `""` as key and `1e7` as value. `""` is a valid key when tried in the validator.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ok, I'll remove the `this` code. As for the `""` with `1e7`, that won't work unfortunately. `1e6` outputs `1000000.0`, but `1e7` outputs `1.0E7` instead.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I didn't check.

Answer (score 5):

#### PHP, 19 bytes

```
<?='{"'.(9**9).'":1}';
```

Output: `{"387420489":1}`

https://eval.in/665889

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for the tips!

Comment: Your output is 16 characters long, while the requirement is 15. So why not remove that “H”?

Comment: BTW, since PHP 5.6 there is a `**` operator: `pow(9,9)` → `(9**9)`.

Comment: 15 chars (not really PHP): `{"<?=9**9?>":1}`

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 5, <strike>16</strike> 15 bytes

<strike>Uses [the unix timestamp of the moment the program was started](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#BASETIME) as the content of a one-element object. **It gives valid output if you run it later than 10:46:39 on 3rd of March 1973**. But since we can't go back in time that seems legit.</strike>

```
say"{\"$^T\":1}"
```

Uses the [FORMAT_TOP_HANDLE variable `$^`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#FORMAT_TOP_NAME) which defaults to `STDOUT_TOP`.

```
say"{\"$^\":1}";
```

Run with `-E` flag at no additional cost.

```
perl -E 'say"{\"$^\":1}";'
```

Outputs is 16 bytes long.

```
{"STDOUT_TOP":1}
```

Comment: RIP time dependent answer :(

Comment: @CalculatorFeline hu?

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6) + jQuery, 15 bytes

Because jQuery.

```
_=>`{"${$}":0}`
```

Outputs `{"function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}":0}` when called. Try it here:

```js
f=_=>`{"${$}":0}`
alert(f())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The assignment is to output something. without the `alert()` you are not outputting anything

Comment: @nl-x The OP has edited to clarify that functions that return the string are allowed.

Answer (score 5):

## Windows batch, 10 bytes

```
{"%OS%":5}
```

The environment variable `OS` contains the string `Windows_NT` (On all Windows operating systems since 2000, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788720/environment-variable-to-determine-the-os-type-windows-xp-windows-7) question on Stack Overflow)

Comment: @ETHproductions Oops

Comment: Is this actually outputting anything? [Neil](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)'s [Batch answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97366) certainly does, but can't remember about any implicit batch output.

Comment: @manatwork Yes it does, since echo is turned on, the current command is echoed, evaluating the OS variable in the process.

Comment: Oh. So actually it tries to execute that `{"%OS%":5}` as it would be a command and you benefit of the elementary tracing feature? That's tricky.

Comment: @manatwork Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5):

## HQ9+, 15 bytes

```
{"Quineland":0}
```

Outputs itself. I thought an 8-byte answer would be possible, like so:

```
{":11QQ}
```

This outputs `{":11QQ}{":11QQ}`, which is *almost* valid JSON, but `11QQ` is not a valid value.

HQ9+ is [not a valid programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073) by PPCG standards, but the OP has allowed non-programming languages.

Comment: This absolutely is not valid. All submissions must be in a valid programming language.

Comment: This is mostly kolmo complexity (mostly, because if it outputs something different it still counts), so I think this could be valid

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Using a non-programming language is a [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8094/45941).

Comment: @Mego OP has explicitly allowed non-programming languages now

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, 18 bytes

`echo {\"$PATH\":1}`

This works on Mac and Linux, unless your $PATH isn't set.

Comment: This is genius. +1. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
“{"":}”s2jȷ4
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCceyIiOn3igJ1zMmrItzQ&input=&args=)**

#### How?

```
“{"":}”s2jȷ4 - Main link: no arguments
“{"":}”      - literal ['{','"','"',':','}']
       s2    - split into twos -> [['{','"'],['"',':'],['}']]
         j   - join with
          ȷ4 - literal 10000 -> ['{','"',10000,'"',':',10000,'}']
             - implicit print -> {"10000":10000}
```

---

previous (13):

```
“"11”m0“{:}”j
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Element](http://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 18 bytes

```
\{\"a\"\:`9 9^`\}`
```

[Try it online!](http://element.tryitonline.net/#code=XHtcImFcIlw6YDkgOV5gXH1g&input=) Outputs `{"a":387420489}`

This is only three bytes shorter than the naive solution.  The first half of the output is hard-coded (too many escape characters to make any other approach feasible), while the value is calculated as `9^9` to make a number long enough.

Answer (score 3):

## Cheddar, <s>17</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ConorO'Brien*

```
->'{":1234}'*2
```

An anonymous function that returns `{":1234}{":1234}`, which is a valid JSON object:

```
{
  ":1234}{": 1234
}
```

[**Try it online!**](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=cHJpbnQneyI6MTIzNH0nKjI&input=)

Answer (score 3):

### [Charcoal](http://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
{"⁹":9}
```

[Try it online!](http://charcoal.tryitonline.net/#code=eyLigbkiOjl9&input=)

Runs of printable ASCII characters in Charcoal form literal strings, and expressions lacking any explicit command are printed. So `{"` and `":9}` are just output verbatim. `⁹`, however, is an integer literal, and when you print an integer, you get an ASCII-art line that many characters long. The character used for horizonal lines is the hyphen, so the result is:

```
{"---------":9}
```

Conveniently, this is exactly 15 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## IBM/Lotus Notes @Formula, <s>24</s> 23 bytes

Computed value in a Notes field.

```
"{\"\":"+@Text(@Pi)+"}"
```

Outputs:

```
{"":3.14159265358979}
```

Nothing clever - just uses the shortest possible function that outputs a number then converts it to text for display.

Comment: Useless? Why? You can still refer that value by its key and use it: http://pastebin.com/RqbbUBEt

Comment: I guess so. If it is considered acceptable then I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

## q, 14 bytes

Prints memory usage information about the current process

```
-1@.j.j .Q.w`;
```

Sample output:

```
q)-1@.j.j .Q.w`;
{"used":127392,"heap":67108864,"peak":67108864,"wmax":0,"mmap":0,"mphy":16735457280,"syms":585,"symw":18925}
```

Comment: Could you provide sample output?

Comment: sure, updated post

Comment: You can just pass the entire .q namespace to .j.j for 7 bytes. This returns a JSON object: `.j.j .q`

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 11 bytes

There are a multitude of 11-byte programs:

```
`\{"{O}":1}  // {"[object Object]":1}
`\{"{M}":1}  // {"[object Math]":1}
`\{"{@}":1}  // {"function (X,Y,Z){return }":1}
`\{"{_}":1}  // {"function (Z){return Z}":1}
`\{"{Ð}":1}  // {"Tue Oct 25 2016 12:15:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)":1}
`\{"":{+Ð}}  // {"":1477412000095}
```

The last two use the Date object; thus, they are non-constant, but always output more than 15 bytes. Explanation:

```
`\{"   ":1}` // Take this string, 
    {O}      // inserting variable O here.
             // O is an Object, which stringifies to "[object Object]".
             // Implicitly output.
```

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=YFx7IntPfSI6MX0=&input=)

More interesting 12-byte version:

```
`\{":{L²}}`²
```

Prints `{":10000}{":10000}`. Explanation:

```
`\{":    }`   // Take this string, 
     {L²}     // inserting 100 squared (10000) here,
              // (this yields {":10000})
           ²  // and double.
              // Implicitly output.
```

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=YFx7Ijp7TLJ9fWCy&input=)

Answer (score 2):

### Common Lisp, 24 bytes

```
(format t"{~S:~f}""p"pi)
```

Prints the following to standard output (23 characters long):

```
{"p":3.141592653589793}
```

This is a simple string format which uses the predefined constant `PI`.

Answer (score 2):

## CoffeeScript, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Caffeinated.tech*

```
->'{"":'+1/3+'}'
```

Outputs `{"":0.3333333333333333}`. Sadly, because of the required double-quotes, string interpolation is a byte longer:

```
->"{\"\":#{1/3}}"
```

Comment: You can use the fact that float division is default in Coffee, which let's us use `1/3` instead of `undefined` to give the length of the required output.
I got it to 16 chars: `->'{"":'+1/3+'}'`

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech The main reason I didn't think of that was that I didn't realize that Coffee's functions could be arg-less, so thanks for teaching me that :)

Answer (score 2):

**Actionscript 3, 27 bytes**

`trace(JSON.stringify(int));`

outputs

`{"MAX_VALUE":2147483647,"length":1,"MIN_VALUE":-2147483648,"prototype":{}}`

Answer (score 2):

**TSQL(2016 only), 50 BYTES**

```
SELECT*FROM(VALUES(GETDATE()))AS A(a)FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: You don't require the `AS ` for the alias and `NEWID` instead of `GETDATE` will save a couple as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 (Full Program), <strike>125 Bytes 123 Bytes</strike> 116 Bytes

Yes, I know there are shorter ways in Java, as posted above. I just wanted to approach it from a looping perspective.

Thanks to ais523 for saving 2 bytes.
Thanks to Manatwork for saving 7 bytes.

```
interface C{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;i++<9;)System.out.print(i<2?"{":"\""+i+"\":"+i+(i>8?"}":","));}}
```

Ungolfed

```
interface C{
    static void main(String[]a){
        //Loop from 0-8, add one to i at start of loop instead of end though
        for(int i=0;i++<9;)
            //If it is a start case simply print { otherwise print "i":i
            //If it is an end case also print } otherwise also print :
            System.out.print(i<2?"{":'"'+i+"\":"+i+(i>8?"}":","));
        }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to keep with this algorithm (which is almost certainly not the best for optimizing your score), you can nonetheless make the program a bit shorter by using `<` and `>` comparisons rather than `==`.

Comment: Good idea, I'll update the code. I don't know why but I really wanted to make a loop.

Comment: You have an accidental `\`` left at the end of your golfed code. While removing it, you could also remove the unnecessary `{`…`}` around `for`'s only statement and change `"\""` → `'"'`.

Comment: There would be one more way to reduce it: `i<2?"{":"\""+i+"\":"+i+(i>8?"}":",")`. With this the `"1":1,` part vanishes from the output, though it remains long enough to be valid.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Sorry, @LlewVallis, but my suggestion only saved 7 bytes, as the last one is not compatible with the earlier `'"'`. But there would be another little trick to recover that 1 character saving: use `i` only in the key and hardcode the value. `i<2?"{":"\""+i+"\":1"+(i>8?"}":",")`.

Comment: @manatwork Just realised, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 17 bytes

Slightly unclear on how strict the 'no input' thing is, if it's just no user input or of system input is also disallowed. While my best answer isn't shorter than the other PowerShell answer I think it is novel.

```
ps|ConvertTo-Json
```

Gets running processes (default return is an object) and converts that object to a json. Several other two and three letter aliases commands work.

Sample output omitted because it's 34115 lines long and trying to redact my username and computername was a pain.

```
gl|ConvertTo-Json
```

Gets your current filesystem location (as an object) and converts that object to a json

```
gci|ConvertTo-Json
```

Gets the files in your current path (as an object) and converts that object to a json

You can also take things like inherent type definitions (which are part of the language itself) and pipe them into the conversion function.

```
[xml]|ConvertTo-Json
```

Gets the definition of the xml datatype and converts that object to a json

```
[int]|ConvertTo-Json
```

Gets the definition of the 32bit integer datatype and converts that object to a json

Comment: So, `ps` is valid in my book, because you're depending on the fact that there are processes running in the system.  `gl` and `gci` depend on things that you *can't* necessarily assume, so are invalid IMO.

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 13 keystrokes

```
a{"<esc>9aa<esc>a":0}
```

Outputs

```
{"aaaaaaaaa":0}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
`0:`j@`a!1e9
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLMLBKyHJISFQ0TLUEABePA4Y=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 47 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(){Print(`{"X":10,"Y":20}`)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6Fjf1M3ML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jQ0qwOKMvNKNBKqlSKUrAwNdJQilayMDGoTNGsh2jaBFYKMAarlAmrggkosWAChAQ)

#### To STDERR, 32 bytes

```go
func(){print(`{"X":10,"Y":20}`)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_B5oLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK6yxCKFNNulpSVpuhY3FdJK85I1NKsLijLzSjQSqpUilKwMDXSUIpWsjAxqEzRrIeo2gZSBtQPVcqVpaHJBJRYsgNAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-n`, 12 bytes

```
""|match("")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19JqSY3sSQ5Q0NJSfP//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

`env` does not always satisfy the requirement. It depends on the environment, which could even be empty, outputting `{}`. This solution yields the same result every time:

```json
{
  "offset": 0,
  "length": 0,
  "string": "",
  "captures": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 machine code, 16 bytes

```
B8 7B 22 3A 20 AB AB AB AB C7 07 30 7D 7D 00 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHdS8MwFMWfm7/iWBlN3QfdnEP24Yt7FWUICtsesiRtA20qTTdbZv91a7ox9MWXe8@95/DLhfB@xHnTMJOCYuVSMoiSbMcShCScOml2gGRlD97Rwxc815vP71sxtWI4aRWsGo2JY4rMiH9ai1m@Pa@WeHldYZ0LtbXI4ISsL8j6ggzOwFwWxHfhz8ghUwIh5THLb2DsglwrzZO9kJibQqhsED8QonSBlClNfXIkThtGLs0@KdZ3w9F2RpyQnmcLcD5yGw@p2zFuD7/rX2OjnxiPlZbgmZBTt3XbF0osEPRQ2VFkOF7i6ASjd4uqFpTutVGRlgKng/3QX5fd7taf1fiMVSJBK1xZSPl4@/cS0I7Criqk8Tfakkpr1k3zzcOERabpp5OxLfafFjYvkx8)

Produces `{": {": {": {": 0}}`.

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI a memory address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated byte string.

In assembly:

```
f:  mov eax, '{' | '"'<<8 | ':'<<16 | ' '<<24
            # Put this value in EAX.
    stosd   # Write it to the output string, advancing the pointer.
    stosd   # Again.
    stosd   # Again.
    stosd   # Again.
    mov DWORD PTR [rdi], '0' | '}'<<8 | '}'<<16 | 0<<24
            # Add this value to the output string.
    ret     # Return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/turtl-d/), 15 bytes

```
'{r'"10:'"r":3}
```

#### [Try it online](http://turtled.tryitonline.net/#code=J3tyJyIxMDonInIiOjN9&input=)

outputs `{"         ":3}`

### Explanation

```
'{               write {
  r              move right, off {
   '"            write "
     10          put 10 in register
       :         move right that many characters (puts spaces in)
        '"r       write ", move right of that character
           ":3}   write :3}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 43 Bytes

```
{groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([i:1..9]​)​}
```

It gives the range 1-9 in JSON stored for i:

```
{"i":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
```

## Groovy on Grails, 31 Bytes

```
def v(){render(params as JSON)}
```

Controller method, renders the parameters which always include action, controller and a few other meta parameters which results in:

```
{"action":"v","format":null,"controller":"<Controller Name>"}
```

When you visit the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/<Controller Name>/v
```

Comment: Your program should take no input.

Comment: @NathanMerrill fixed, the only cool part to my answer is the Grails part anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Myth](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Myth), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
{"a":"{\":3141}","_":"aa"}
```

Saved 2 bytes by adapting the solution given by the `///` answer.

Myth is a language similar to Thue, contained in a valid JSON object. How appropriate! Here, `_` is the initial state, and replaces `a` with `"****"`. Output:

```
{":3141}{":3141}
```

For clarity, I added some spaces:

```
{
  ":3141}{"  :  3141
}
```

### Previous solutions

28 bytes: `{"a":"\"****\"","_":"{a:a}"}`. Outputs: `{"****":"****"}`

### Running

I found the interpreter [here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Myth#Reference_implementation_in_JavaScript_.28137_bytes.29):

```
function(m,y,t,h){m=JSON.parse(m);for(y=m._;h=1;){for(t in m)if(t!="_"&&~y.indexOf(t)){y=y.replace(t,m[t]);h=0;break}if(h)break}return y}
```

Test it out right here:

```js
function myth(m,y,t,h){m=JSON.parse(m);for(y=m._;h=1;){for(t in m)if(t!="_"&&~y.indexOf(t)){y=y.replace(t,m[t]);h=0;break}if(h)break}return y}
b.onclick=function(){o.innerHTML="";o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myth(q.value)));}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 90%;
}
*{font-family:Consolas,monospace;}
```

```html
<textarea id=q>{"a":"\"****\"","_":"{a:a}"}</textarea>
<br>
<button id=b>execute myth code</button>
<br>
<textarea id=o disabled>output</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Addict](https://github.com/ETHproductions/addict), <s>200</s> 167 bytes

Addict is a Turing tarpit where the only control flow is user-defined commands.

```
a A
 i 1
 i 1
 d
a B
 A 1
 A 1
 d
a C
 B 1
 B 1
 d
a D
 C 1
 C 1
 d
D b
D b
D b
D b
D b
D b
D b
C b
B b
d b
D q
D q
A q
c b
c q
c q
D q
C q
c q
n b
n q
n b
n q
A b
c b
```

This outputs `{"":1235812358}`. Try it in the [online interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/addict/)!

### How it works

To golf answer space, I'm going to refer you to the sections **Primer on Addict** and **Act I** on [**"Hello, World!" in Addict**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94734/42545). If you already know how that works, feel free to skip this part.

### Act II

The rest of the program is devoted to outputting a valid JSON object in as few bytes as possible. In order to minimize the code, we can use the variables that are already set to output a number with the `n` command. The first step is then to set three variables to the two chars we need at first:

- `b` to 123, the char code of `{`
- `q` to 34, the char code of `"`

After these have been set, we output `{""` one char at a time, then increment `q` by 24, resulting in 58, the charcode of `:`. We output that, then output the values of `b` and `q` twice, printing `1235812358`. The last step is to increment `b` by 2 to change it to `}`, and then output it to finish.

If you can find any way to golf this program, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

## [Crystal](http://crystal-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```
puts %Q({"#{"a"*9}":0})
```

You can also avoid using `%Q` (and keep the same character count):

```
puts "{\"#{"a"*9}\":0}"
```

The above return:

```
{"aaaaaaaaa":0}
```

Which has exactly 15 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

```
'}Qè;':@'{
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=J31Rw6g7JzpAJ3s&input=)

Explanation:

```
'}Qè;':@'{
'}          push "}"
  Q         push this program's source code
   è        call Python's repr function (essentially just wraps the string in double-quotes)
    ;       duplicate
     ':@    push ":", swap with one copy of double-quoted source code
        '{  push "{"
            implicitly print each stack item, separated by newlines, starting with the top
```

Output:

```
{
"'}Qè;':@'{"
:
"'}Qè;':@'{"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 14 bytes

```
'{"":'+1e9+'}'
```

Gives:

```
{"":1000000000}
```

I know that this doesn't actually print out anything, it merely returns. But so do all other Javascript solutions here.

Comment: You need to *either* define a function, or a full program (with printing).

Comment: @NathanMerrill allmost all other javascript/ecmascript solutions do no printing. The rule about function or program was added later.

Comment: I guess it's a REPL?

Answer (score 1):

## [RAGE!!!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/RAGE!!!), 41 bytes

```
<rant>SCREAM"{\"12345\":54321}"!!!</rant>
```

Since the <strike>interpreter</strike> <strike>compiler</strike> transpiler on the esolangs page converts the code to Python 2 via mere string substitution, escaping double quotes should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 2015, 16 bytes

```js
_=>`{"":${9e9}}`
```

*It will run in most modern ECMAScript environments (eg. Firefox, Chrome, MS Edge, Opera, Node…).*

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript, 17 bytes**

```
_=>'{"'+{}+'":0}'
```

outputs

> {"[object Object]":0}

passes validator at jslint

This works because `{}` will implicitly be cast to string with the `+` concatenation, and calling `toString` on an object returns "[object Object]".

Answer (score 1):

**C#, 39 bytes**

```
string j(){return"{\""+1.0/0+"\":42}";}
```

In C#, division of 0 with a double (hence the inclusion of .0), will result in Infinity.

Output:

> {"Infinity":42}

Comment: Cool. Do you need the `0` in `1.0`, or will `1./0` suffice?

Comment: `1./0` is a syntax error in c#, namely "Identifier expected". Nice thought though :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 13 bytes

```
print{"'":.1}
```

Outputs:

```
{"'": 0.10000000000000001}
```

Since tenths can't be stored exactly in binary Python outputs a 1 followed by 15 zeros followed by a 1 after the decimal point. Need double quotes around the single quote to not have the double quotes converted to single quotes (thanks to @JonathanAllan's comment to @xnor's answer).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work the same way here: http://pastebin.com/P5vau3WB

Comment: @manatwork Works with QPython on my android

Comment: @manatwork And Python 2.6.6 but not Python 2.7.1

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 21 bytes

```rs
||"{\"a\":0.1234567}"
```

String substitution would be too verbose, but at least there's always terse lambdas with implicit returns.

With "test code":

```rs
fn main(){
    let f=||"{\"a\":0.1234567}";
    println!("{}", f());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 27 bytes

```
?"{
?CHR$(34)*2;":
?PI();"}
```

Printing quotation marks is a huge pain in BASIC. 8 bytes wasted!

#### Output:

```
{
"":
3.14159265}
```

Exactly 15 characters, without the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 12 bytes

```
`{"`A`":1}`"
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@59QrZTgmKBkZViboPT/PwA)**

This produces the output:

```
{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":1}
```

Any text wrapped in backticks is a string literal. The `A` injects the whole uppercase alphabet. Then, the final `"` command prints it all.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
„{"A„":Jû¨'}J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYV61kiOQVLLyOrz70Ar1Wq///wE)

`{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":"zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"}`

Comment: Your code outputs single quotes instead of double

Comment: @user2428118 fixed at a -2byte cost. JSON with `'` is parsable in some languages though.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Doubt it. It's probably not actual JSON if single quotes are parsable, maybe you meant dictionaries?

Comment: @Makonede There's an extension of JSON called JSON5 that allows single-quoted strings, unquoted keys, trailing commas, and a whole host of other things that aren't part of standard JSON.

Comment: @Bbrk24 ok.. that's not JSON though

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 18 bytes

```
puts \{"[pwd]"\:4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCGmWim6oDwlVinGyqT2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 19 bytes

```
?-writeq({"":1e7}).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/3163vCizJLVQo1pJycow1bxWU@//fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```
echo "{\"\":",4/9,"}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/NTkjX0GpOkYpRslKScdE31JHqVbp/38A)

Boooring.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
"{~k:~k}"gj₃w₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X6m6LtuqLrtWKT3rUVNz@aOmxv//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## GNU nano, 9 keystrokes

```js
{"              ":0}
```

<kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>META</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd>

<kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>: literal `{"`

<kbd>META</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>: switch to tabs-to-spaces mode

<kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Tab to the second tab stop (tab stops are 8 by default). Since we enabled tabs to spaces, these will be converted to 14 spaces.

<kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd>: literal `":0}`

It is a very interesting JSON string with a very interesting input method, if you ask me.

[Video demo](https://streamable.com/tu8j9g) done in Termux to visualize keystrokes (<kbd>ALT</kbd> is <kbd>META</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
`{"‹":0}
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJge1wi4oC5XCI6MH0iLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Outputs `{"https://www.google.com":0}`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `KJ`, \$ 13 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 10.70 bytes

```
":0}"'"AZ'"'{
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_WbSSt5dS7IKlpSVpuhZrlawMapXUlRyj1JXUqyFiUKkFUBoA)

Prints `{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":0}`

##### Explanation

Since Thunno's stack is reversed, we'll go right to left:

```
":0}"'"AZ'"'{  #                      STACK:
           '{  # Push "{"             {
         '"    # Push '"'             { "
       AZ      # Push the alphabet    { " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
     '"        # Push '"'             { " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
":0}"          # Push ":0}"           { " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ " :0}
               # Flags: join stack    {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":0}
               # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 26 bytes

```
"{"o:o"o,S"!So"o"o*}@o,o!o
```

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#%22%7B%22o%3Ao%22o%2CS%22!So%22o%22o*%7D%40o%2Co!o).

Most of this is just spent shuffling punctuation around. Prints out

```json
{"":58
,"":1972
}
```

Which, while not particularly useful, is accepted by `JSON.parse`. The first number is the value of `':'` and the second number is `'"' * ':'`.

### Trilangle, no duplicate keys, 30 bytes

```
"{:ooS"!oo""SS!o,oo"oooS*}@.",
```

Prints out:

```json
{"":58
,":":1972
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 18 bytes

```
say"{'".[2]."':1}"
```

Prints an array reference in quotes as the name and 1 as the value.  Sample output:

```
{'ARRAY(0x60002b5c0)':1}
```

Comment: This isn't valid JSON because strings must be delimited with double quotes (not single quotes as you currently have it).

Comment: Chrome console accepts it just fine

Comment: @GabrielBenamy Unfortunately, standard JSON is different from Javascript objects, and doesn't allow single quotes. Source: http://www.json.org/

Comment: If you're changing the quotes anyway, you can remove the `2` in the `[]` and it'll still be an arrayref for -1!

Comment: Another alternative: `say"{\"$~\":$]}"`!

Comment: You can save one byte by using a scalar ref, but then you need commas. `say"{'",\2,"':1}"`

Comment: AFAIK is still invalid. -1.

Answer (score 0):

## C++11, 30 bytes

As unnamed lambda, port of [jrich](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97310/53667)'s answer, -1 byte thanks to ETHproductions

```c++
[](){printf("{\"\":%f}",9e9);}
```

Usage:

```c++
int main(){
 [](){printf("{\"\":%f}",9e9);}();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
~C`0]]1Y
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7EC%600%5D%5D1Y)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 76 bytes

```c#
using System;public class P{public void Main(){Console.Write("{\"\":"+1/3d+"}");}}
```

Output:

```js
{"":0.333333333333333}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can omit the `using System;` and use instead `System.Console.Write(...)`. This can save you 6 bytes

Comment: @auhmaan: D'uh. You're correct. I *had* that, but I switched from `Math.PI` to `1/3d` since it's shorter. And because I had to use `System` for both `Console.Write` and `Math.PI` it was shorter to use a `using`. But now I'm not using `Math.PI` anymore I can, indeed, get rid of the `using system`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby (cheap), 22 bytes

```
->{'{"aaaa":"bbbbb"}'}
```

Lambda function that returns the `String` object `'{"aaaa":"bbbbb"}'`

Comment: `"a":"b"*8` would be shorter.

Comment: @carusocomputing See my other post.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (REPL)

10 chars:

```
{"":{}+''}
```

Output:

> `{"": "[object Object]"}`

Well, maybe. If it doesn't like the bare object:

12 chars:

```
({"":{}+''})
```

If it doesn't print returned objects the way we need:

This is cleaner (ES2015, 13 chars, borrowing from another solution):

```
`{"":${9e9}}`
```

> `{"": 9000000000}`

Answer (score 0):

## [Text](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Text), 15 Bytes

I'm pretty sure you know that language, and non-programming languages are allowed...

```
{"hi ":"world"}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ShellSoccar-jpn/Parsrs makrj.sh](https://github.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs/blob/666042eddeb41406ee4a1e4831a01b0aac5af211/makrj.sh), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

Tested with version `Wed Sep 14 22:19:55 JST 2016`, which is the latest version before this problem was created.

```
.../
```

outputs (18 bytes w/o LFs)

```json
{
"":{
"":{
"/":""
}
}
}
```

## Explained

makrj.sh is a POSIXism utility to generate a JSON object from a list of JSONPath-indexed values developed by ShellShoccar-jpn. The input shall be lines of `<key> <value>`.

```sh
.../  # define an implicit value "" with 3-level key whose
.     # 1st-level key name is ""
 .    # 2nd-level key name is ""
  ./  # and 3rd-level key name is "/"
```

### Try this (bash+curl)

```bash
printf '.../' | sh <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShellShoccar-jpn/Parsrs/666042eddeb41406ee4a1e4831a01b0aac5af211/makrj.sh)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ẠṘ"{%:0}"Œ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboW6x_uWvBw5wylalUrg1qlo5OWFCclF0PlYGoA)

##### Explanation

```python
ẠṘ"{%:0}"Œ  # Full program
  "{%:0}"   # Template string "{%:0}"
         Œ  # With the "%" replaced by
 Ṙ          # A quoted version of
Ạ           # The lowercase alphabet
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score -1):

## Boring answers with literals

### Emotinomicon, 32 bytes

```
}1:"        r"{⏪⏬⏩
```

### Minecraft, 19 bytes

```
say {"           ":0}
```

#### Or not so boring, but not guaranteed

```
say @p
```

And just use the JSON as username

### Any texteditor, 15 bytes

Couldn't get it any shorter with copy-pasting

```
{"123456789":0}
```

### Notepad, 7 keystrokes

<kbd>{</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

Thanks to @ETHProductions

Comment: I forgot about the qoutes and noticed ah I need 11 chars as key.

Comment: `{":1234}<ctrl+a><ctrl+c><right-arrow><ctrl+v>` is 15 keystrokes, I suppose, but that's not any shorter, and I'm not sure it would count...

Comment: Yes I tries some copy-pasting but got the same problem you got. :(

Comment: In Notepad on Windows 7 (perhaps other OSs too), you can do `{"<F5>":0}` for a grand total of 7 keystrokes (F5 inserts the time/date, e.g `3:37 PM 10/25/2016`). Not sure if that counts either...

Comment: Do you know this html tag which looks like keyboard buttons. You know the one that is sometimes uses in Vim answers. I already searched for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: I think it's `<kbd>`

Comment: `say @p` gives >= 15 bytes of JSON?!

Comment: @cat No. It prints your username. Which can be set to any string you want.

Comment: `"{}:` are not allowed in Minecraft usernames; therefore the result will *never* be valid. Even if, somehow, you were able to change your Minecraft username to `{"           ":0}`, it would count as 25 bytes as per [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/94066). (It's about storing extra info in the file name, but I'm sure this counts as well.)